# Adding Gtk::Entry to Gtk::Dialog

Tags: c++, dialog, gtkmm, gtkentry

I am adding a `Gtk::Entry` to `Gtk::Dialog`.

```
Gtk::Dialog *dialog = manage ( new Gtk::Dialog() );
dialog->set_title("Add Text");

Gtk::Entry entry;

entry.set_activates_default(true);
entry.set_max_length(50);
entry.set_text("hello world");
entry.select_region(0, entry.get_text_length());

dialog->add(entry);
dialog->show();
```

This code shows an empty dialog box. On using `show_all()` or `show_all_children()`, nothing happens, not even an empty dialog box shows up.

And I get the following warning in all cases:

`Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type gtkmm__GtkEntry to a gtkmm__GtkDialog, but as a GtkBin subclass a gtkmm__GtkDialog can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkVBox`

Help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Gtk::Dialog` already has a VBox added to it. Looking at the source file of Gtk::Dialog class, I found `get_vbox()` function. I had to access the VBox to add further components to the dialog.

```
dialog->get_vbox()->pack_start(*entry, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);
dialog->set_text("hello world");

dialog->set_size_request(200,100);
dialog->show_all();
```

And it works all fine.

Comment: Oldie but goldie. Very good answer!